# Symfony2 Doctrine Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

Well I was looking for any kind of help that might resolve my problem, but after all I am still getting same error.

I am trying to get some News from my database which are in a selected category. 
Relation between News and Categories is many-to-many over Doctrine.

```
<?php
//News
namespace Core\DatabaseBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
class SfNews
{
    private $date;
    private $header;
    private $content;
    private $contentPlain;
    private $id;
    private $sfUsers;
    private $sfUploadedFiles;
    private $sfCategories;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sfUploadedFiles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->sfCategories    = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    // Some code removed
    public function setSfUsers(\Core\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Users $sfUsers = null)
    {
        $this->sfUsers = $sfUsers;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getSfUsers()
    {
        return $this->sfUsers;
    }
    public function addSfUploadedFile(\Core\DatabaseBundle\Entity\SfUploadedFiles $sfUploadedFiles)
    {
        $this->sfUploadedFiles[] = $sfUploadedFiles;
        return $this;
    }
    public function removeSfUploadedFile(\Core\DatabaseBundle\Entity\SfUploadedFiles $sfUploadedFiles)
    {
        $this->sfUploadedFiles->removeElement($sfUploadedFiles);
    }
    public function getSfUploadedFiles()
    {
        return $this->sfUploadedFiles;
    }
    public function addSfCategorie(\Core\DatabaseBundle\Entity\SfCategories $sfCategories)
    {
        $this->sfCategories[] = $sfCategories;
        return $this;
    }
    public function removeSfCategorie(\Core\DatabaseBundle\Entity\SfCategories $sfCategories)
    {
        $this->sfCategories->removeElement($sfCategories);
    }
    public function getSfCategories()
    {
        return $this->sfCategories;
    }
}

//Categories
namespace Core\DatabaseBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
class SfCategories
{
    private $name;
    private $id;
    //code removed
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    private $sfNews;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sfNews = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function addSfNews(\Core\DatabaseBundle\Entity\SfNews $sfNews)
    {
        $this->sfNews[] = $sfNews;
        return $this;
    }
    public function removeSfNews(\Core\DatabaseBundle\Entity\SfNews $sfNews)
    {
        $this->sfNews->removeElement($sfNews);
    }
    public function getSfNews()
    {
        return $this->sfNews;
    }
    //code removed
}
```

Code I was trying to use is:

```
$Sfcategory = $this->em->getRepository("CoreDatabaseBundle:SfCategories")->findOneBy(array("url"=>$category));
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $qb
       ->select('p')
       ->from("CoreDatabaseBundle:SfNews","p")
       ->where($qb->expr()->like('p.sfCategories', ':id'))
            ->setParameter('id', $Sfcategory->getId())
       ->setMaxResults($count)
       ->orderBy('p.date', 'DESC');
    $r = $qb->getQuery();

    return $r->getResult();
```

ORM Via XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="Core\DatabaseBundle\Entity\SfNews" table="sf_news">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="date" type="datetime" column="date" nullable="true"/>
    <field name="header" type="string" column="header" length="255" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="content" type="text" column="content" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="contentPlain" type="text" column="content_plain" nullable="false"/>
    <one-to-one field="sfUsers" target-entity="Users">
      <join-columns>
        <join-column name="sf_users_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
      </join-columns>
    </one-to-one>
    <many-to-many field="sfUploadedFiles" target-entity="SfUploadedFiles" inversed-by="sfNews">
      <join-table name="sf_news_has_sf_uploaded_files">
        <join-columns>
          <join-column name="sf_news_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
        </join-columns>
        <inverse-join-columns>
          <join-column name="sf_uploaded_files_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
        </inverse-join-columns>
      </join-table>
    </many-to-many>
    <many-to-many field="sfCategories" target-entity="SfCategories" inversed-by="sfNews">
      <join-table name="sf_news_has_sf_categories">
        <join-columns>
          <join-column name="sf_news_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
        </join-columns>
        <inverse-join-columns>
          <join-column name="sf_categories_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
        </inverse-join-columns>
      </join-table>
    </many-to-many>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="Core\DatabaseBundle\Entity\SfCategories" table="sf_categories">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="name" type="string" column="name" length="255" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="url" type="string" column="url" length="255" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="visible" type="boolean" column="visible" nullable="true"/>
    <many-to-many field="sfNews" target-entity="SfNews" mapped-by="sfCategories"/>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Error I am getting is:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 50 near 'sfCategories': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

Im looking forward to any kind of way to solve the problem.
Thanks

Comment: Could you paste your Doctrine mapping information? Could you paste what is the value of $category in the last code chunk? Is $count variable defined?

Comment: I think you are posting way too much code. Try to focus on the parts of the code that are relevant to your problem. Also, most of the comments in your code could be removed before posting it so there is less scrolling.

Comment: Post has been edited,

$count is defined, and set as (int)5

Comment: Well, i know that **SfCategories** as **getSfNews()** method, but in this way i have to create another join that order such news in **(date:Desc**) and also limit them to **$count** param.